# Redirect ssh output to file while performing other commands

Tags: bash, ssh, parallel-processing, sh

I'm looking for some help with a script of mine. I'm new at bash scripting and I'm trying to start a service on a remote host with ssh and then capture all the output of this service to a file in my local host. The problem is that I also want to execute other commands after this one:

```
ssh $remotehost "./server $port" > logFile &
ssh $remotehost "nc -q 2 localhost $port < $payload"
```

Now, the first command starts an HTTP server that simply prints out any request that it receives, while the second command sends a request to such server.
Normally, if I were to execute the two commands on two separate shells I would get the first response on the terminal, but now I need it on the file.
I would like to have the server output all the requests on the log file, keeping a sort of open ssh connection to receive any new output of the server process.

I hope I made myself clear.
thank you for your help!

EDIT: Here's the output of the first command:
[(Output is empty in the terminal... it waits for requests).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf7Dz.jpg)
As you can see the commands doesn't return anything yet but it waits.
When I execute the second command on a new terminal (the request), the output of the first terminal is the following:
[The request is displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLMBA.jpg)
Now I would like to execute both commands in sequence in a bash script, sending the output of the first terminal (which is null until the second command is run) to a file so that ANY output, triggered by later issued requests, is sent to a file.

EDIT2: As of now, with the commands above, the server answers any requests but the output is not registered in the log file.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: It looks like the first command ought to be saving the output of the remote command to the log. What actual problem are you having? I presume this code that you've posted is pseudocode. It would be helpful to see your actual script and to know what actual command you're running on the remote system, and what exactly happens when you run it.

Comment: The question is: how to do what I am describing? I've added a few images to show how the server reacts to requests.
Thank you guys

Comment: From my point of view, the commands you showed us should work. If you don't give us the exact script that is failing and don't tell us which is the failure, we cannot help.

Comment: I added the real commands, but I doubt they'll make anything clearer.... The first command should send all the output of the server to the file but it doesn't: if you telnet to the webserver it will answer but still without outputting anything to the logfile.